# Solarwinds migration

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, network-monitoring

I want to migrate my solarwinds to a new VM ware. Currently my solarwinds is installed in a Windows Desktop with the database stored locally in it.
During migration to a VM ware, I want to point the database to a dedicated SQL server. How can i do this with minimal downtime.

Comment: SolarWinds and VMware are companies, not products. What SolarWinds and VMware products are you referring to?

Comment: Hi Hoeqwerty, I want the migrate the Orion NPM to a virtual machine which is currently stored in a dedicated Hardware and I want to point the database to a sql server which is stored locally now.

Answer (score 1):

This pdf from Solarwinds should cover migration information:
http://www.solarwinds.com/documentation/orion/docs/OrionServerMigration.pdf